# How to randomize customer personal data like email, mobile number and address etc in any SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to randomize customer personal data in `Customer` table but format and length for the data should remain the same. Mobile number should be replaced with any random number of same length, email should randomize with any other email but still remain a valid email. First name, Last Name can be anything but should not be duplicate.

I do not want any exact solution for this issue. Just suggest me if SQL has any ability to do the same or any cursor/query etc can be used to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL itself doesn't offer much help here - but there are plenty of tools - usually called **Test Data Generator** or something similar that allow you to create sample data, based on certain rules (like "valid e-mail" etc.)

Comment: Redgate offers such functionality: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/ but it's a paid tool.